# "deviceready has not fired" error in Cordova 10.0.0

Tags: android, cordova

When I run the project in the android 9 version, I got this error:

```
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady
Channel not fired: onFileSystemPathsReady
```

I am using cordova 10.0.0 version, and the plugins as following:

```
ca-cleversolutions-zebraprinter 0.0.3 "ZebraPrinter"
cordova-plugin-camera 6.0.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-datecs-printer 0.10.0 "DatecsPrinter"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2 "File"
cordova-plugin-jcore 1.4.1 "JCore"
cordova-plugin-media 5.0.3 "Media"
cordova-plugin-vibration 3.1.1 "Vibration"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.5 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x5-webview 3.1.0 "X5 WebView Engine"
```